# learning from open source code

Tags: search, open-source, projects

I'm a student and I have a lot of free time on this vacation so I decided to put some time in learn more about how to write good code.(All I know at this moment is C and some C++)

My question is about how to find some applications source code? 
Let's say I'm looking for some source codes which are using a specific library. How can I find the open source projects which are using the library about I'm interested.

I've tried on google code and sourceforge but without success. I think i don't know how to search. Do you have any advice/link about how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a one-stop-shop for finding open source code.

If you want to read some **well written code**,  **GNU's Savannah** is a browsable repository of the GNU stuff (Binutils, GCC toolchain and tons of others). The GNU software, IMHO is some of the best written C anywhere.

You could also checkout **MINIX** which is an open-source microkernel based operating system (which is POSIX compliant too).

The **Gnome project** has many projects that cover a wide range of languages from C to Python and even C# (FSpot).

When **searching** for a project, if you know the name, google should help. If not, search for the library on google such as "libfoo", or look in the **metadata** of the package manager you use (it often has the upstream maintainer's website).

For example:

```
[aiden@devbox ~]$ ldd /bin/ls
    ...
    libcap.so.2 => /lib64/libcap.so.2 
    libacl.so.1 => /lib64/libacl.so.1 
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 
    ...
```

I could google "libpthread" to find that it is part of the [GNU C Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)

If you want to **get involved** in FOSS/C then learn to use source control systems like **Git** or **subversion**, and diff for making patches. Talk to people, they always want fresh developers to triage bugs and fix problems. But you will probably find a pecking order and a social ladder to climb.

- [GNU Savannah](http://savannah.gnu.org/)
- [MINIX 3](http://www.minix3.org/)
- [Gnome Projects](http://projects.gnome.org/)
- [Git Distributed Version Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software))
- [Free book on Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)
- [The Linux Kernel](http://www.kernel.org/)

Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 3):

http://www.google.com/codesearch is your friend.

Comment: quote:
"I've tried on google code and sourceforge but without success. I think i don't know how to search. Do you have any advice/link about how to do that?"

Answer (score 1):

If there are specific methods that you know are included in the library, then you can always search for those.

Alternatively, if the library has an irc channel or a newsgroup set up, then ask the question on there.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at "The Dragon Book" if you can find it.  Spinelli's [Code Reading](http://www.spinellis.gr/codereading/) is also good.  Both will help you understand the code you're reading.

Answer (score 1):

There is a one-stop-shop for finding open source code.

It's called [google codesearch](http://www.google.com/codesearch) and searches in lots of open source projects.
To find code using a specific library, just search for the term you use to include it in code, for example [#include <libusb.h>](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=%22%23include+%3Clibusb%22&sbtn=Search) or [import ipaddr](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=%22import+ipaddr%22&sbtn=Search).

Answer (score 0):

[Koders](http://www.koders.com/) may be helpful. It is a search-engine for source-code.

Answer (score 0):

Visit Launchpad.net and get in touch with the friendly Ubuntu Community. This is a good place to start cause they are not that harsh if you ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Hanselman has a series on [his blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/) called [The Weekly Source Code](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CategoryView.aspx?category=Source+Code) which is worth checking out.

Answer (score -1):

Four "easy" steps:

1. Select a free application you enjoy using
2. Think about a feature it lacks
3. Try to discover how to implement this feature
4. Do it

Point 1 and 2 will retain you doing things.

With point 3 you will learn how to download sources, read patches and understand the code of different people.

And with point 4 you will practise coding and, if you like, you can start to officially collaborate with the project :)